# Scala Type Aliases and Method Overloading

Tags: scala, types, overloading

I'm writing some Scala that deals with intervals on a linear time line. Currently intervals' starts and ends are both represented as `Int`s, however, there are situations where I want to treat them slightly differently (but they still need to be `Int`s for handing to some external code).

I thought this was the sort of situation where a type alias would be a nice way to add some compile time checking and I could handle the different processing via method overloading. Here's an illustrative example:

```
type IntervalStart = Int
type IntervalEnd = Int

case class Interval(s: IntervalStart, e: IntervalEnd)
val i = Interval(1, 10)

def process(s: IntervalStart): Unit = { println("Do some start specific work") }
def process(e: IntervalEnd): Unit { println("Do some end specific work") }

process(i.s) // "Do some end specific work" WRONG!!
process(i.e) // "Do some end specific work"
```

It appears as though it doesn't properly overload the `process` method and always chooses the later definition. Is this a limitation of Scala type aliasing, some weird JVM type erasure thing, or a misunderstanding of the correct behaviour on my part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type alias is just an alias, it changes nothing about the type itself. `IntervalStart` and `IntervalEnd` are still `Int`s, therefore `process(s: IntervalStart)` and `process(e: IntervalEnd)` have the same signature, which is illegal.

You could declare them like this:

```
case class IntervalStart(i: Int)
case class IntervalEnd(i: Int)

def process(s: IntervalStart): Unit = ...
def process(e: IntervalEnd): Unit = ...
```

But then you'd have to create actual `IntervalStart` and `IntervalEnd` objects to pass. If both functions will do different things, I think you should just name them differently.

```
def processStart(s: Int): Unit = ...
def processEnd(e: Int): Unit = ...
```

Comment: The **alias** should have given me the main clue! I was thinking that `type IntervalStart` was a _new_ type. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The two `process` methods erase to the same method, which is an error:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

type IntervalStart = Int
type IntervalEnd = Int

def process(s: IntervalStart): Unit = { println("Do some start specific work") }
def process(e: IntervalEnd): Unit = { println("Do some end specific work") }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:11: error: method process is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file '<console>'
       def process(e: IntervalEnd): Unit = { println("Do some end specific work") }
           ^
```

You probably tested your methods in the REPL by declaring them *consecutively* (but **not** together), so you didn't get an error, the second one just shadowed the first one (that's how the REPL enables you to "redefine" something already in scope).

Comment: well spotted I did just type it into the REPL. I'll need to remember to do `:pa` on future examples.

Comment: @Alastair `:pa` is short for `:paste`, btw.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the alias you're looking for:

```
package object tagged {
    type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
    type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]
}
package tagged {
    trait Start
    object Start {
        def apply(i: Int): Int @@ Start = i.asInstanceOf[Int @@ Start]
    }
    trait End
    object End {
        def apply(i: Int): Int @@ End = i.asInstanceOf[Int @@ End]
    }
    case class Interval(start: Int @@ Start, end: Int @@ End)
    object P {
        def p(i: Int @@ Start) = s"Start at $i"
        def p(i: Int @@ End)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = s"End at $i"
    }
    object Test extends App {
        Console println (P p Start(9))
        Console println (P p End(5))
        val x = Interval(Start(9), End(5))
        Console println (P p x.start)
        Console println (P p x.end)
    }
}
```

The DummyImplicit is the way to disambiguate the runtime signatures.

http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html